# what is the docker run -g switch actually doing?

Tags: docker

Can't seem to find it in the docs, would like to understand what its actually doing. The only examples I can seem to find with this switch is for `nginx -g 'daemon off'` so its the magical make nginx stay running switch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-g` switch is actually not a docker argument, but an [nginx argument](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nginx).

Have a look at the `docker run` syntax:

```
$ docker run --help
Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Everything you specify after the command (`nginx` in your case) will be treated as an argument *to that command*, not to `docker run`.

Comment: oh duh, OK that obviously makes perfect sense. So I can be sure that everything after IMAGE are just local commands to the container and not docker specific stuff